# Displaying text in ListBox while adding SearchResult object

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding Users from Active Directory to my `ListBox`.
The object I got from Active Directory is `SearchResult` and this is what I add to my `ListBox`. The problem is I don't know how to display as a text value of SearchResult object property.

`ListBox` displays "System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult" while I would like to have displayed "John Smith" (which is "cn" property in my SearchResult object)

Here is my code:

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="SearchListbox" Margin="5 5 5 0" Height="100"/>
<telerik:RadListBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="AddListbox" Margin="5 5 5 0" Height="100"/>
```

CS:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry.Path)
{
    Filter = "(&(cn*)(sn=*)(mail=*)(givenName=*))"
};
var results = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult result in results)
{
    SearchListBox.Items.Add(result);
}
```

I can't use `ItemSource` because I want to transfer object from one `ListBox` to another and with `ItemSource` I can't simply delete object from `ListBox`.

Any idea how to handle that?

UPDATE, SOLVED PROBLEM WITH NOT CHANGING ObservableCollection:

full working code:

```
    private ObservableCollection<SearchResult> resultsSearch = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>();
    private ObservableCollection<SearchResult> resultsAdd = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>();

    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> ResultsSearch
    {
        get { return resultsSearch; }
        set { resultsSearch = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> ResultsAdd
    {
        get { return resultsAdd; }
        set { resultsAdd = value; }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChange(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }


    public void Add(SearchResult item)
    {
        this.ResultsSearch.Add(item);
        this.OnCollectionChange(
          new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }

    public void Remove(SearchResult item)
    {
        this.ResultsSearch.Remove(item);
        this.OnCollectionChange(
          new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the name of the user you have to set the `ItemTemplate` property:

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="SearchListbox" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
    SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="5 5 5 0" Height="100">
    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Properties[cn]}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

Best practice will be to create a ViewModel class around the `SearchResult` model. In this case your ViewModel will declare a `FullName` property that will access the dictionary in your model for the actual value:

**SearchResultViewModel.cs**

```
public string FullName 
{ 
    get { return searchResult.Properties["cn"];} 
}
```

You should avoid tying down your View to your business logic. Using the above ViewModel the binding will look like `Text="{Binding FullName}"`, this removes the necessity to create complicated binding.

> I cant use ItemSource because I want to transfer object from one
>   ListBox to another and with itemSource I cant simply delete object
>   from ListBox.

Yes you can, just use an `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource`. The UI will be updated when you make changes to this collection.

Comment: I checked your solution but it doesnt work. I got empty field, like binding didnt work. Should I add some code in CS to apply this binding?

Comment: I updated my question, Could you help me understand that ItemsSource?